# Individual column filtering using datatable

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, datatable, codeigniter-3

My target is to have an individual filtering for column. My reference is: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html

The problem I am encountering right now when I type, my datatable doesn't do any filtering and it shows an error regarding `CURSORPOSITION`:
[image]
[image]

I followed the guide thoroughly and made a lots of research but I still failed to achieve my goal. I hope you can help me

**Views:**

```
 <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped is-narrow is-hoverable is-fullwidth text-nowrap" style="width: 100%;">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            
            <th>TESTING ID</th>
            <th>TESTING ACTION</th>
            <th>TESTING DESC</th>
            <th>TESTING Date</th>
            <th>TESTING VENUE</th>
            <th>TESTING TICKET</th>

          
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             </tbody>          
            </table>
```

**Ajax:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    
    
    
    $('#example thead tr')
            .clone(true)
            .addClass('filters')
            .appendTo('#example thead');
        
            table = $('#example').DataTable({ 
            
    
            
            dom: 'lfrtip',
            "processing": false, //Feature control the processing indicator.
            "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.    
    orderCellsTop: true,
            fixedHeader: true,
            
                            initComplete: function () {
                var api = this.api();
     
                // For each column
                api
                    .columns()
                    .eq(0)
                    .each(function (colIdx) {
                        // Set the header cell to contain the input element
                        var cell = $('.filters th').eq(
                            $(api.column(colIdx).header()).index()
                        );
                        var title = $(cell).text();
                        $(cell).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" />');
     
                        // On every keypress in this input
                        $(
                            'input',
                            $('.filters th').eq($(api.column(colIdx).header()).index())
                        )
                            .off('keyup change')
                            .on('change', function (e) {
                                // Get the search value
                                $(this).attr('title', $(this).val());
                                var regexr = '({search})'; //$(this).parents('th').find('select').val();
     
                                var cursorPosition = this.selectionStart;
                                // Search the column for that value
                                api
                                    .column(colIdx)
                                    .search(
                                        this.value != ''
                                            ? regexr.replace('{search}', '(((' + this.value + ')))')
                                            : '',
                                        this.value != '',
                                        this.value == ''
                                    )
                                    .draw();
                            })
                            .on('keyup', function (e) {
                                e.stopPropagation();
     
                                $(this).trigger('change');
                                $(this)
                                    .focus()[0]
                                    .setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
                            });
                    });
            },
     
            // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo site_url('controller/lists')?>",
                "type": "POST",
                 async:true,
                 dataType: "json", 
                 
             
                 "data": function(data){
                 
                  
               
               
                },
                
            },
     
            //Set column definition initialization properties.
            "columnDefs": [
                { 
                    "targets": [ 0 ], //first column
                    "orderable": false, //set not orderable
                },
                { 
                    "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
                    "orderable": false, //set not orderable
                },
                
     
            ],
     
        });
        
    
    
            
        
    
    });
```

Comment: You are using `"serverSide": true` which delegates all filtering (and sorting and paging) to the server. This option is intended to be used when you have too much data for the browser to handle in one response.  Do you really need that option? It means all client-side filtering (and sorting and paging) is disabled. (Your `cursorPosition` problem looks like a separate issue on top of that - the variable is declared in a different scope from where it is used.)

Comment: I have tried to set it "serverSide": false and my data is not showing anymore. I have tried to remove it also and it stays the same (No show). Any suggestion on what approach should i do?

Comment: Use the approach where you remove all your custom code, until you have the simplest solution which actually works with no errors, using your Ajax-sourced data (or, start with an empty page and add the most basic code to that). Then start making your customizations, one-by-one, until you break something again.

Comment: Okay, i'll start from the very beginning. I'll keep you updated. Thanks.

Comment: It works now. I just want to say thank you for recommending me to start from the scratch. I have tried also using datatable without serverside. Finally i can do the sorting per column individually. Kudos to you. Thank you again. Appreciated your efforts.

Comment: Will post it later. Thank you for reminding me